# Проблема с отображением кастомного Preference-элемента

Tags: android, android-preferences

Проблема заключается в том, что основные данные о настройке (title & summary) располагаются в правой части элемента списка, а почему так происходит, я не могу понять. Должны же ведь располагаться слева, как положено. Скриншоты загрузить не могу, т.к. почему-то происходит ошибка при загрузке.

```
public class MyListPreference extends ListPreference {

private TextView title, summary;

public MyListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.icon_list_preference);
}

@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);

    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pref_title);
    summary = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pref_summary);

    title.setText("ASDASDASD");
    summary.setText("}P}{P}P}{");
    }
}
```

xml самого view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pref_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pref_summary"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Устанавливать кастомный layout нужно не через `setWidgetLayoutResource()`, а через `setLayoutResource()`. В чем разница этих методов, пока нет информации, но второй работает действительно корректно.

Comment: `setWidgetLayout` используется для установки лейаута при отображении виджетов приложения на главном экране